# Regex to replace all leading characters not a-Z

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all non-letter characters that appear at the start before any letter
for example

> $ %5hello w8r^ld  becomes  hello w8r^ld

This regex I got now works greate for replacing none word characters but does not replace numbers

```
s.replaceFirst("^[\\W_]+", "")
```

Comment: `\\w` means "word characters" but it really means characters that can be in an identifier in most languages, i.e. `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `_`.  `\\W` means everything except those.  That's why it didn't replace the digits.  You could use `[\\W_\\d]` to add the digits back in, like you already did with `_`, but I think `[^A-Za-z]` is clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong character class. Use

```
s.replaceFirst("^[^a-zA-Z]+", "")
```

That is

```
^          start at the beginning of the string
[^  ]+     one or more (greedy - keep going until you hit a letter
a-zA-Z     ascii characters between a-z or A-Z
```

Following comments from @anubhava, I changed the `*` to a `+`. If you have no match, there is nothing that needs replacing. It's actually cleaner.

Comment: If there is nothing then why bother replacing that with `""`

Comment: @anubhava fair point - I like to make my expressions match what I say I want to match... "If there is anything like this". I guess the `+` means "only replace if there is something worth replacing. " I have updated my answer accordingly.